# Git on Amazon Server

Tags: amazon-ec2, permissions, git

I have git running on an Amazon server and up til now I have been the only one to use the server. I use my Amazon ssh key to connect and am then connected as root on the server without the need for any username and password.

Now, a second user needs access to the git repository, but I don't want this person to have root access to the machine as I have many other services running there. How can I grant them just access to the git files? Can I do it without needing to give them the ssh private key?

EDIT: After a lot of problems, I had luck generating the key on Amazon - not optimal but I need to get working: http://utkarshsengar.com/2011/01/manage-multiple-accounts-on-1-amazon-ec2-instance/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new user account for them, set group membership and ownership/permissions such that they have read/write access to the repo. Have the user generate their own key pair, and then deploy their public key to the server.

Comment: Thanks. How do I associate that user to that public key so that when they login they log in as that user?

Comment: They supply their username, and you've previously added their public key to their account. These two steps are very rudimentary Linux sysadmin, and you should look for guides elsewhere if you need assistance with them.